# Does a print version of the Java 1.5 API exist?

Tags: java, api

Does a print version of the Java >= 1.5 API exist? Where can I buy it online? Preferably in Canada, but just a title is great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Java in a Nutshell](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/reader/0596007736/ref=sib_dp_pt/026-8599590-2045232#reader-link) by O'Reilly

Answer (score 0):

you can download the entire api documentation as a static website from [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/?intcmp=1281).  I use it a lot when im away from an internet connection.

Comment: Would be long and costly if you have to print it out... :-) But good tip anyway.